# label not showing in html when using datalist

Tags: html, forms

Why is the label not showing while using datalist in html if anyone have any idea of why this is not running then please help me..

i tried the same code in another new file then it worked perfectly but when run in this it won't show the label.
p.s. i am using brave browser but it won't show in other browsers too..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    <title>forms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <div id="backgnd">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://images-platform.99static.com//1qWC_KuhJeSkGLZV6M7fC3g5Xb4=/113x113:848x848/fit-in/500x500/99designs-contests-attachments/81/81740/attachment_81740257" alt="burger's logo">
        </div>
        
        <form action="/button.html">
            <h1>Enter your Credentials</h1>
            <p>
             A perfect place to order your favoriate burgers..reach us or order online 
            </p>

            <label for="number">number of burgers to be ordered</label>
            <br>
            <input type="number" name="no_user" id="number" step="1">
            <br><br>
            <label for="spiciness">
                <ins>Level of your Spiciness</ins>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <span>not spicy</span>
            <input type="range" name="spicy" id="spiciness" max="10" min="0" step="0.01">
            <span>really spicy</span>
            <br><br>

            <section class="topping">
                <ins>select the topping you would like</ins><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="lettuce" id="lettuce">
                <label for="lettuce">lettuce</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="tomato" id="tomato">
                <label for="tomato">tomato</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Onion" id="Onion">
                <label for="Onion">Onion</label>
            </section><br><br>

            <section class="Answer">
                <strong>what type of burger would you like to have</strong> <br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" id="veg">
                <label for="veg">Veg</label>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" id="Non-veg">
                <label for="Non-veg">Non-veg</label>
            </section><br><br>

            <section class="Burger_type">
                <label for="Burger">
                    <strong>What kind of burger would you like to have?</strong>
                </label><br>
                <select name="burger" id="Burger">
                    <option value="veggie-burgers">Veggie Burgers</option>
                    <option value="beef-burgers">Beef Burgers</option>
                    <option value="portobello_mushroom-burgers">Portobello Mushroom Burgers</option>
                    <option value="black_bean-burgers">Black Bean Burgers</option>
                </select>
            </section><br><br>


            <section class="sauce">
                <label for="sauce">
                    <!------------------------ label not showing-------------------> 
                    <strong>What type of sauce would you like?</strong>
                </label><br>
                <input type="text" list="sauces" id="sauce" name="sauce">
                <datalist id="sauces">
                    <option value="ketchup">Ketchup</option>    
                    <option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
                    <option value="yoghurt">Yoghurt</option>
                </datalist>
            </section>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML where your form and label are.

Comment: @KnightTheLion here it is..

Comment: It is showing in Chrome on windows 11.

Comment: @Mehrwarz so is it the problem of OS in it..i am currently using windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <section class="Burger_type">
    <label for="Burger">
        <strong>What kind of burger would you like to have?</strong>
    </label><br>
    <select name="burger" id="Burger">
        <option value="veggie-burgers">Veggie Burgers</option>
        <option value="beef-burgers">Beef Burgers</option>
        <option value="portobello_mushroom-burgers">Portobello Mushroom Burgers</option>
        <option value="black_bean-burgers">Black Bean Burgers</option>
</select> <!-- You didn't close this tag -->
    </section><br><br>
```

I commented where the issue was.

I use VS Code for my IDE, and in VS code I have Prettier installed, I use this to format my code for HTML, CSS, and JS when I am done playing for the moment. It helps clean things up. If you have an error in your code for HTML, Prettier will not format the document, and it will give you a reference to where and why. When I closed the select tag, your input formatted properly on the page. It was simple with Prettier. Not saying use Prettier, but it is handy to have some type of formatter to help clean things up and to see easily overlooked issues like this one.

Comment: thank you very much for your correction. the code is perfectly running now..i have already installed prettier in my vscode but don't know why it didn't correct the error

Comment: Awesome, make sure that Prettier is your default formatter. VS Code could've possibly switched to another. When you right click your code, choose format with, and choose Prettier. Also up top it will tell you if it is the default. If you would be so kind as to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

we've all been there, but your `<select>` element is not closed, I think thats the issue you were having.

Answer (score 0):

your question has already been answered up there. You're just missing a closing select tag.

```
<select>
  ** code **
  <option value="black_bean-burgers">Black Bean Burgers</option> <--- after this block
</select> <--- missing this (not closed)
```

but here I want to suggest some VSCODE extension to make your coding easier.

besides only using code formatter like prettier or beautify extension in VSCODE. you can also use

Name: ***Auto Rename Tag***
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag

Name: ***Auto Close Tag***
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Name: ***indent-rainbow***
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow

Name: ***IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML***
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

Name: ***CSS Peek***
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek

i hope these extension can help